# Apache Beam maven dependencies: jdbc package is not downloaded in skd jar file

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Downloaded maven dependecies in eclipse using

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
<artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
<version>0.3.0-incubating</version></dependency>
<dependency>
```

Only org.apache.beam.sdk.io,Only org.apache.beam.sdk.io.range are downloaded.
but .io.jdbc is not being downloaded in dependencies.

Is there any other specific artifactId I have to use for this other than the above mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Beam (incubating) publishes several convenience binaries to [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3Aorg.apache.beam) with every release.

There isn't an artifact that captures the whole project. Instead, you should be using specific components that you actually need (perhaps core SDK, any additional libraries, and a runner).

Specifically, if you'd like to use Beam's JDBC connector, depend on the following artifact (among other things):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
  <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>${some_version}</version>
<dependency>
```

Also, we are currently adding [Quickstart](http://beam.incubator.apache.org/get-started/quickstart/) to our webpage, which will cover some of this information. At this moment, this is still work-in-progress.

Answer (score 0):

You can Directly Download the jar file and put it into your project library. The link to download is-

[Org.apache.beam.sdk.io.java.jdbc](https://jar-download.com/?detail_search=g%3A%22org.apache.beam%22%20AND%20a%3A%22beam-sdks-java-io-jdbc%22&search_type=av&a=beam-sdks-java-io-jdbc)